# How do you structure a German sentence to represent the English construct "at [action]"?

Tags: english-to-german, verb

For example, how would one phrase the sentence, "I am getting better at riding a bike." in German? I have a feeling the flow of the sentence wouldn't be very similar to English at all.

> Ich werde besser beim Fahren des Fahrrads.

I have no idea if "bei" is right here, or another preposition would be more appropriate. Assuming whichever appropriate preposition is used, this still seems like a really awkward (possibly wholly incorrect) sentence.

How do you represent this notion in German?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Carsten pointed out above, I would rephrase this in german as

> Ich verbessere mich (beständig) im Radfahren.

or

> Ich werde im Radfahren immer besser.

The structure with `beim Radfahren` could also mean that you improve (in whatever) while cycling. Of course one usually implies the other here, but consider the following:

> Ich habe die besten Ideen beim Radfahren.

Here, the cycling is only a method to help you in something, but the improvement is not in riding the bike.

Answer (score 4):

> Ich `werde besser` beim Fahren des Fahrrads.

This sentence indicates that you are `getting better` **while** driving. You actually don't say anything about *at what* you are getting better. `beim Fahren` is an `adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit` and it would come *before* the predicate. I think this is why the sentence sounds odd.

> Beim Fahren des Fahrrads werde ich besser [...].

The brackets need to be filled with at what the speaker gets better at.

Let's see another example

> `Als ich` gestern die Straße `überquerte`, streifte mich ein Radfahrer.

this can be put

> Gestern, `beim Überqueren` der Straße, streifte mich ein Radfahrer

The context tells, that the action `Überqueren` was accomplished by the speaker (`streifte mich`) and in both cases the meaning is the same:

> `when I was crossing` / `while crossing`

The question you would ask actually is

> **At what** are you getting better? (action)  **At** riding a bike.
>   **Worin** verbesserst du dich? (Handlung/Tätigkeit) **Im** Radfahren.

Answer (score 3):

Meine Meinung: Das würde man ganz anders  ausdrücken: Ich kann jetzt schon viel besser radfahren.

Hier irgendeine Form von Gerund zu gebrauchen wäre für gesprochene Sprache ganz untypisch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least from my knowledge there is no real 1:1 translation for the at something thing. In your example most of the Germans would say `Ich werde besser beim (Fahrradfahren/Radfahren)` I think. But your proposal seems to be fine. In most cases I'd say `beim` followed by nominalization version of your verb.

Comment: I realize that it's not going to directly translate. I am interested in how Germans would convey the same message. If what you say is right then I'm amazed at how close I came :P

Comment: I think `beim` is the best solution for this case.

Comment: Nein, die deutsche Konstruktion ist “im Radfahren“.

Comment: "gut in -> besser in -> verbessern in"